# For one specific font, why the same font size looks different in different apps?

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, truetype-fonts

I see the difference quite often between apps. For example see the attached screenshot. Both [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) and [Terminus](https://github.com/Eugeny/terminus) are using the font `Fixedsys Neo+`. I'm using size `11` in PuTTY but for Terminus I have to use size `15` for the same look-and-feel.

So why the difference even the apps are all running on the same Windows OS (win10 for me)?

---

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is 15 inches longer than 15 centimeters if the number is the same? :)

Putty is measuring font size in [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)), Terminus is using pixels. With computers it's often assumed that `1 pt = 1.33 px`. Thus 11 pt is just slightly less than 15 px and 15 px is about 11.25 pt.

Comment: on the screen everything is printed as pixels right? so how it handles 11pt since it's not mapping to an exact num of pixels? that's to say, for 11pt, will it round up to 15px eventually?

Comment: @pynexj Depends on implementation. There are at least three ways to handle this. You can round 11pt to 15px immediately and calculate everything starting from there. You can do all calculations with 14.63px and do the rounding just before conversion to pixels (results will be slightly more accurate). You can not round at all and let font smoothing handle rendering at non-integer offsets.